Sequelize should support schema for MySQL
The Sequelize docs state that

Apply a schema to this model. For postgres, this will actually place the schema in front of the table name - "schema"."tableName", while the schema will be prepended to the table name for mysql and sqlite - 'schema.tablename'.

I'm a bit confused why Sequelize does this for MySQL.
I would like to use the schema "feature" in MySQL and it seems to work as expected (ie. works as for postgres) if I use the following hack:
sequelize.dialect.supports.schemas = true

If I specify a schema on a table, then I would expect it to be used as a schema and not merely prepended to the table name. It does not make sense to me that Sequelize works as it does and does not even expose an API to tell it to use the schema correctly, rather a hack using internals is required.
I cannot find a MySQL option for this.
Am I missing something here? Is this a bug or a feature request?

Could you point to the MySQL documentation that says about schema feature?

Not really. I could only find "The syntax of table_factor is extended in MySQL in comparison with standard SQL." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html I could not even find any docs for "standard SQL". Some clues in https://www.vertica.com/docs/10.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/SELECT/table-ref.htm and https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/11.0.0?topic=esql-referencing-columns-in-database

I suppose for MySQL the mentioned syntax 'schema.tablename' is just for convinience. If you don't indicate a schema you'll end up with just tablename

Thanks @Anatoly, I will raise a feature request.
